# Is it possible to specify which grid-area inline text flows into?

Tags: css, layout, css-grid

If I have a parent node that contains child nodes.

I can specify a grid layout on the parent and pick which `grid-area`s the child nodes will be rendered in:

```css
.parent {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  display: grid;
  grid:
    ".    .   .   ." 1rem
    ".    a   .   ." 1fr
    ".    .   b   ." 1fr
    ".    .   .   ." 1rem
    /1rem 1fr 1fr 1rem;
}

.a {
  grid-area: a;
}
.b {
  grid-area: b;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="a">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
  <div class="b">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
</div>
```

If, instead of one of the child nodes I have a text node, is it possible to specify which `grid-area` the text nodes flow into?

```css
.parent {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  display: grid;
  grid:
    ".    .   .   ." 1rem
    ".    a   .   ." 1fr
    ".    .   b   ." 1fr
    ".    .   .   ." 1rem
    /1rem 1fr 1fr 1rem;
}

.a {
  grid-area: a;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="a">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
  
  <!-- can this text be made to flow into grid-area b? -->
  lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, since the text node is laid out as an anonymous grid item, you cannot control how the anonymous grid item is laid out.

(You might be able to affect its layout by manipulating surrounding non-anonymous grid items, but obviously that's going to be hit-and-miss depending on your actual grid setup. It's very unlikely you are going to be able to have an anonymous grid item occupy all of a specific grid area.)

Comment: I guess I should have looked a bit closer at the spec: ["Anonymous grid items are always auto-placed, since their boxes can’t have any grid-placement properties specified."](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#auto-placement-algo).

Comment: @zzzzBov: Generally, when you have an anonymous box, the answer to any of your layout questions is "you can't control it". Remember that you cannot target an anonymous box in any way - *because they are anonymous*. They don't have a representation in the DOM, even if they do have one in the formatting structure.

Comment: Yea, it mostly makes sense to me, my main problem was connecting "text node" to "anonymous grid item". Still, would be nice to be able to specify default placement from the parent node, but it's easy enough to work around by wrapping everything in `div`s.